# How do I prove the following properties about prime numbers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $p$ be a prime number not equal to 2 or 3

1. Prove that $p\equiv 1\pmod{6}$ or $p\equiv -1\pmod{6}$
2. Prove that if $p+2$ is also a prime,then $p+1$ is divisible by 6

Comment: Hi jai, welcome to MSE! What have you tried? This is not a forum where people just do your HW for you. Please see
https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960

Comment: @bounceback Yes i have tried,its not homework,just really want to learn the solutions to these questions :)

Comment: @jairamanathan but what have you tried? You should show us first. Think about what would happen if the statement were false (proof by reductio ad absurdum).

Comment: How do i upload an image?

Comment: @jairamanathan While editing the post there is an icon to insert an image.

Comment: But please don't insert images unless absolutely necessary.  Use MathJax for mathematical expressions.

Comment: Not very good at latex expressions

Comment: [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a tutorial for MathJax

Answer (score 2):

Since $p$ is divisible by neither $2$ nor $3$, the residue classes $0,\,\pm 2,\,3$ are excluded, leaving only $\pm 1$.  If $p,\,p+2$ both fulfill this, we need $p\equiv -1$.

Comment: What are residue classes?

Comment: residue classes are what a number could be congruent to $\pmod 6$

Answer (score 0):

$1.$ $p$ cannot be $0$ mod $6$, or it would be divisible by $6$ and thus not be prime. If it were $2$ or $4$  mod $6$ it would be divisible by $2$ and thus not prime. I'll let you finish why it cannot be $3$ mod $6$.

$2.$ $p+1$ must be divisible by $2$, since $p$ must be odd. As a hint for how to complete this, consider $p$ mod $3.$

Answer (score 0):

**Hints**:

1. Any number is congruent to $0,\pm 1, \pm2,3\bmod 6$. Can it be prime in the other cases?
2. This means that, if $p+2$ is also prime, then $p\equiv -1\bmod 6$? What can $p+2$ be congruent to if it is prime?